# time complexity of MemberQ

Tags: core-language, expression-test

I was rather surprised that the operator form of MemberQ takes a form as its argument.  I looked for the operator form thinking that repeated testing for elementhood in a *given* "set" is a common need and might be supported in WL by converting a list to a hashtable, turning an O(n) query into an O(1) query at the cost of forming the table.

i. What is the application of the actual operator form provided?

ii. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Well, to search for the same thing in different lists :-)  To search for different things in the same list I would construct an association with the list elements as keys and whatever as values and then use Lookup.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'd use `Intersection` if I had them all available at once, but otherwise your approach at least gives access to a hashtable lookup.  What about (i)?  (I don't mean as a generality, but an actual application.)  Why did they make this decision, which currently looks backwards to me?

Comment: Of course I can only guess.  But this is just a different form for an operator.  Building a hash table would mean that `MemberQ[list]` needs to evaluate to something else first (i.e. a hash table).  Operator forms of functions never evaluate unless applies to something.  In this sense the behaviour you are asking for would not be consistent with the other operator forms anyway.

Comment: @Szabolcs That is a helpful response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MemberQ`'s operator form seems to be useful for searching for the same value in different lists.

If you need to search for different values in the same list many times, I would build an association that has the list elements as keys, and then use `Lookup`.  For example,

```
list = RandomInteger[10, 10]
(* {3, 8, 9, 3, 8, 3, 5, 8, 9, 5} *)

asc = AssociationMap[True &, list]
(* <|3 -> True, 8 -> True, 9 -> True, 5 -> True|> *)

Lookup[asc, 3, False]
(* True *)

Lookup[asc, 4, False]
(* False *)
```

Comment: +1. There actually is `PositionIndex` for that, which is faster than top-level implementation, and takes into account duplicate elements. Although for simply testing the presence of an element, this latter detail isn't necessary.

Comment: One case where your method would be more economical would be a list with huge multiplicities of elements, where `PositionIndex` would take vastly more memory, to store details not actually needed for membership tests. I personally actually usually you the same method as you suggested here, although do it slightly more formally (introduce a `Set` data structure based on assoc).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Can you post an example implementation?

Comment: @Leonid If we are aiming for the fastest creation speed, then `AssociationThread[list -> ConstantArray[1, Length[list]]]` is faster than `PositionIndex[list]`. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tPUyg.png)

Comment: @Alan I could, but I am using something I call interfaces, for that, and the total answer would be quite long and probably for no good reason in the context of your specific question. Also, I don't have the time for that at the moment. But basically, you can define a symbolic wrapper like `SetType`, so that your instance would look like `SetType[<|obj1 -> True, ..., objn -> True|>]` and methods like `HasElement`, `AddElement`, `RemoveElement`, `SetToList` and such, via `UpValues`, to have a reasonably general version of a set data type.

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed, you are right. All that matters is the presence of an element as a key. I think I did not read the question very carefully at first, and thought that the OP needed some info on elements positions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to demonstrate `Nearest`, even though `NearestFunction` is about 10-20 times slower than `Lookup`.  On the other hand `Nearest` is faster at creating the underlying data structure than `AssociationMap`/`PositionIndex`.  The use of `Lookup` seems clearer than this indirect use of `Nearest`, so the interest may be only academic.

```
list = RandomInteger[10^9, 10^6];

asc = AssociationMap[True &, list]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.80475, Null}  *)

asc2 = PositionIndex[list]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.88674, Null}  *)

nf = Nearest[list]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.183863, Null}  *)

foo = list[[Length@list/2]]
(*  35589223  *)

Lookup[asc, foo, False] // RepeatedTiming
Lookup[asc, foo + 1, False] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {2.27*10^-7, True}
  {4.2*10^-7, False}
*)

Lookup[asc2, foo, False] // RepeatedTiming
Lookup[asc2, foo + 1, False] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {2.2*10^-7, {500000}}
  {4.2*10^-7, False}
*)

nf[foo + 1] === {foo + 1} // RepeatedTiming
nf[foo] === {foo} // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {4.765*10^-6, False}
  {4.5*10^-6, True}
*)
```

If `list` changes often enough, you may find `Nearest` performs better overall. OTOH, if the changes are minor, then probably the association `asc` can be directly updated more quickly `Nearest` recomputed. My purpose, however, is not to argue for `Nearest`, but to illustrate its differences with `AssociationMap`/`Lookup`, which I found interesting.

Comment: `Nearest` becomes very interesting when working with floating point numbers, which will be treated as distinct by associations even if they only differ in the last binary digit.

Comment: @Szabolcs Quite right.  One could use `MatchQ` instead of `SameQ`/`Equal` with `Nearest`, if distinguishing strictly different numbers were important.  And otherwise you have to worry about the nontransitivity of equality in *M* with respect to floating-point numbers.  (And, of course, for some data, `Nearest` is likely to be impossible to use and much less efficient.)